# How do I change a specific field based on another field in a unix file

Tags: linux, unix

How do I change a field value to a different value based on the item id present in the same record in a unix file.

For eg: Billing charge rate PI;PAC;4;287301483014;287301483014;5623945596;DBT;SMS;SMS CET;UC;912990299;862733471;203401725;

suppose I want to change the value in field 8 i.e SMS to SMSI based on the item id 203401725 which is present in the same record. I have 8000 records which has 4000 item ids with 203401725 and the remaining are different and I want to update those 4000 records only based on the matching item id 203401725, which is not sequential. How do I do that for files in unix?

Answer (score 0):

The perhaps simplest approach is using [`awk`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html):

```
awk -F\; 'BEGIN {OFS=FS} $13==203401725 {$8="SMSI"} {print}' Billing\ charge\ rate >$$ &&
mv $$ Billing\ charge\ rate
```